# Difference between navigateUp() and popBackStack()

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, navigation

I'm creating a simple ToDo app and checking about the Navigation methods to return to my mainFragment from the AddTask Fragment. And I found that I can return using navigateUp() and also popBackStack(), but I don't understand the difference.

When I use this:

```
Navigation.findNavController(it).navigateUp()
```

Or this:

```
Navigation.findNavController(it).popBackStack()
```

I return to the mainFragment and I think, the addTaskFragment is popped from the stack, so could someone please explain me?

Comment: Would you consider accepting my answer?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Sorry, the (*edit:* previously) accepted answer is absolutely wrong, `navigateUp()` will also pop the top fragment from the backstack, if there is any.

For starters: **If you arrived at your current destination from within your app, they act exactly identical.**

**ONLY if you arrived at the current destination with a deeplink from a different app, they will behave differently:**

`navigateUp()` will leave your app and return to the app that navigated to the deep link in your app.

`popBackStack()` will attempt to go back one step in your backstack, and will not do anything if there is no backstack entry.

You can read up on the differences on:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#navigateUp()

> navigateUp()
> Attempts to navigate up in the navigation hierarchy. Suitable for when
> the user presses the "Up" button marked with a left (or start)-facing
> arrow in the upper left (or starting) corner of the app UI.
>
> The intended behavior of Up differs from Back when the user did not
> reach the current destination from the application's own task. e.g. if
> the user is viewing a document or link in the current app in an
> activity hosted on another app's task where the user clicked the link.
> In this case the current activity (determined by the context used to
> create this NavController) will be finished and the user will be taken
> to an appropriate destination in this app on its own task.

and

> popBackStack()
> Attempts to pop the controller's back stack. Analogous to when the
> user presses the system Back button when the associated navigation
> host has focus.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in short can I say that navigateUp() does remove (or pop) the fragment from the stack or it goes back to the previous fragment(silimar to onBackPressed()).

Comment: @JustGotStared not quite, the simplest description might be that navigateUp returns to a different app IF the user came from there, popBackStack only goes back within the current app. Both will pop the fragment from the backstack if there is any place to return to.

Comment: This is quite odd because the android documentation says the opposite about the back and up button https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#up_and_back_are_identical_within_your_apps_task

Comment: Yes, this confused me in the documentation as well. The functionality description is correct, but the comparison with back and up are mixed. So navigateUp is more like the back button and popBackStack is more like the Up arrow.

Answer (score 2):

It's about android backstack. Whenever you launch an application the activity will be added to activities backstack(`Activity1` e.g.). Now if you start `Activity2`, it'll be added to top of the stack. If you press the back button, the `Activity2` will be destroyed and popped from the top of the stack and the activity which had placed below `Activity2` will be resumed. Check this figure to understand things better. [image]

The stack is working for fragments too. Assuming you launch `FragmentA`, then `FragmentB`. So the stack will be like `FragmentB` on top and `FragmentA` below that. `FragmentB` is showing on the screen now. If you use `popBackStack()` obviously it'll destroy the `FragmentB` and pop it from top of the stack, then it'll check for the current top fragment in the stack, that is `FragmentA`, so it'll be resumed. But if you call `navigateUp()`, it will navigate up through the stack, just like as it's name. When you navigate up from `FragmentB`, you will reach `FragmentA` in the stack again. This is why these two methods have the same output. But the point is that `navigateUp()` will not pop `FragmentB` from top of the stack and it'll not be destroyed.

Comment: This is simply not true, please check my answer.