# LazyColumn reference returns starting position

Tags: java, android

I have an application. A large picture and a LazyColumn at the bottom. When I go to the 4th (or 5th) link and then back, my LazyColumn ends up in the initial position. Link 1 at the very top. And when I want link 4 again I have to “twist”.

The "Back" button on the "native" navigation bar is different. When I return back, LazyColumn is already waiting for me in the form in which I left it.

What needs to be done in the program so that the top button behaves the same way as the "back" button on the navigation bar?

Here are my files:

[image]

**NavGraph.kt**

```
 @Composable
 fun NavGraph(navController: NavHostController){
     NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screens.Contents.route
     ) {
         addContentsScreen(navController, this)
         addScreen1(navController, this)
         addScreen2(navController, this)
         addScreen3(navController, this)
         addScreen4(navController, this)
         addScreen5(navController, this)
     }
 }

 private fun addContentsScreen(
     navController: NavHostController,
     navGraphBuilder: NavGraphBuilder
 ) {
     navGraphBuilder.composable(route = Screens.Contents.route) {
         ContentsScreen(
             navigateScreen1 = { navController.navigate(Screens.Screens1.route) },
             navigateScreen2 = { navController.navigate(Screens.Screens2.route) },
             navigateScreen3 = { navController.navigate(Screens.Screens3.route) },
             navigateScreen4 = { navController.navigate(Screens.Screens4.route) },
             navigateScreen5 = { navController.navigate(Screens.Screens5.route) },
         )
     }
 }

 private fun addScreen1(navController: NavHostController, navGraphBuilder: NavGraphBuilder) {
     navGraphBuilder.composable(route = Screens.Screens1.route) {
         Screen1 (navigateContentsScreen = { navController.navigate(Screens.Contents.route) })
     }
 }

 private fun addScreen2(navController: NavHostController, navGraphBuilder: NavGraphBuilder) {
     navGraphBuilder.composable(route = Screens.Screens2.route) {
         Screen2 (navigateContentsScreen = { navController.navigate(Screens.Contents.route) })
     }
 }

 private fun addScreen3(navController: NavHostController, navGraphBuilder: NavGraphBuilder) {
     navGraphBuilder.composable(route = Screens.Screens3.route) {
         Screen3 (navigateContentsScreen = { navController.navigate(Screens.Contents.route) })
     }
 }

 private fun addScreen4(navController: NavHostController, navGraphBuilder: NavGraphBuilder) {
     navGraphBuilder.composable(route = Screens.Screens4.route) {
         Screen4 (navigateContentsScreen = { navController.navigate(Screens.Contents.route) })
     }
 }

 private fun addScreen5(navController: NavHostController, navGraphBuilder: NavGraphBuilder) {
     navGraphBuilder.composable(route = Screens.Screens5.route) {
         Screen5 (navigateContentsScreen = { navController.navigate(Screens.Contents.route) })
     }
 }
```

**Screens**

```
 sealed class Screens(val route: String) {
     data object Contents : Screens("contents_screen")
     data object Screens1 : Screens("screen_1");
     data object Screens2 : Screens("screen_2");
     data object Screens3 : Screens("screen_3")
     data object Screens4 : Screens("screen_4");
     data object Screens5 : Screens("screen_5");
 }
```

**Screens.kt**

```
 class Item(val link: () -> Unit, val name: String)

 @Composable
 fun ContentsList(explanation: List<Item>) {
     val listState = rememberLazyListState()
     LazyColumn(state = listState) {
         items(explanation.size) { index ->
             val item = explanation[index]
             ContentsButton(
                 onClick = item.link,
                 text = item.name
             )
         }
     }
 }

 @Composable
 fun ContentsScreen(
     navigateScreen1: () -> Unit,
     navigateScreen2: () -> Unit,
     navigateScreen3: () -> Unit,
     navigateScreen4: () -> Unit,
     navigateScreen5: () -> Unit,
 ) {
     val listOfQuestions = listOf(
         Item( navigateScreen1, "Screen1"),
         Item( navigateScreen2, "Screen2"),
         Item( navigateScreen3, "Screen3"),
         Item( navigateScreen4, "Screen4"),
         Item( navigateScreen5, "Screen5"),
     )
     Column {
         Image(
             modifier = Modifier.height(650.dp),
             painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.cat),
             contentDescription = null,
             contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
         )
         ContentsList(listOfQuestions)
     }
 }
```

**Screen4.kt**

```
 @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
 @Composable
 fun Screen4(
     navigateContentsScreen: () -> Unit,
 ) {
     val text = "Screen4"
     Scaffold(
         containerColor = lightGray,
         contentColor = darkGrey,
         topBar = {
             TopAppBar(
                 modifier = Modifier.height(80.dp),
                 title = {
                     Box(
                         Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
                         contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                     ) {
                         Text(
                             maxLines = 1,
                             overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                             text = text,
                             color = orange,
                         )
                     }
                 },
                 navigationIcon = {
                     Box(
                         Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
                         contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                     ) {
                         IconButton(
                             onClick = navigateContentsScreen
                         ) {
                             Icon(
                                 imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
                                 contentDescription = "Back",
                                 tint=orange,
                             )
                         }
                     }
                 },
                 colors = TopAppBarDefaults.mediumTopAppBarColors(
                     containerColor = darkGrey
                 )
             )
         }
     ) { contentPadding ->
         Column(
             modifier = Modifier
                 .fillMaxSize()
                 .padding(contentPadding)
                 .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
         ) {
             Text(
                 text = "Screen4",
                 color = darkGrey,
                 textAlign = TextAlign.Justify,
                 modifier = Modifier.padding(24.dp)
             )
         }
     }
 }
```

I tried and searched and found nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your code as follows:

```
navGraphBuilder.composable(route = Screens.Screens4.route) {
    Screen4 (navigateContentsScreen = { navController.navigateUp() })
}
```

When you use `navController.navigate(Screens.Contents.route)`, you will always create a new `BackStackEntry` of that route, and this new destination will be freshly created without any state. Be careful, you will build up a huge back stack with your current approach.

Using [`navController.navigateUp()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#navigateUp()) or [`navController.popBackStack()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#popBackStack()), you get the actual previous destination. See [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67245601/difference-between-navigateup-and-popbackstack) for an explanation of the differences.

Comment: Yes!!! Happened! Thank you very much)